# I accidentaly did sudo apt-get remove python

Tags: apt, python

I accidentaly did sudo apt-get remove python command and now terminal look has changed, rhythmbox, ubuntu software center and everything is quite changed. I reinstlled python with the command sudo apt-get install python but still nothing reverses. Terminal can't be opened throug dash but only through ctrl + alt + T How to get back the old ubuntu. Ubuntu is still working music is playing videos are being played( In VLC). I can browse net through mozilla. But still how can I reverse the effect? Should I reinstall ubuntu?

I was able to install rhythmbox and software center through uxterminal and then once software center was installed everything was installed and then I install terminal through software center.

Comment: You can try creating another user account and try.

Comment: It will remove 75% of your important system packages.

Comment: Try the following command to install all default packages again: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I think when you removed python, some more programs were removed.But when you installed it, only python was installed.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: after restarting i couldn't find my dash and unity bar i had to reinstall :/

Answer (score 3):

Just switch to the tty, you will have a login prompt, write your username/password, you will get a shell. So, now you only need to install python back, along with all the others packages, the simple way to do so is:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you like, you can also install other metapackages instead:

```
apt-cache search metapackage | grep desktop
```