# Apt-get remove python ~150Mb / apt-get install python 687kb

Tags: 14.04, apt, python

I did

```
sudo apt-get remove python
```

and it told me that about 150 MB would be freed by this operation. Then, after that I did

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

and it told me that 687 kB of additional disk space would be used. How does this add up?

<strike>*Side question: Did I break anything by doing the above? If yes, how do I fix it?*</strike> Edit: [Answered here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437644)

Comment: Just a question. Why did you do `sudo apt-get remove` in the first place ?

Comment: you probably removed things that required python to work...

Comment: @Serg I thought: Who needs python2.7? After I hit `Enter` I realized that maybe some Ubuntu functionality actually needs it. I know it was stupid, but its done now...

Comment: maybe: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` might help get back some essentials?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I accidentaly did sudo apt-get remove python](http://askubuntu.com/questions/437644/i-accidentaly-did-sudo-apt-get-remove-python)

Comment: @Mateo yes, my side question was in fact a duplicate of the question you mentioned, but my main question was not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command

```
sudo apt-get remove python
```

removed the package `python` and any package that depends on it. That's a lot of packages, and it most likely broke parts of your system.

The command

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

just installs the package `python` but not all the other packages that got removed.

You can see the list of all removed packages in the file `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

With the command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

you can install all packages belonging to the default installation. Replace `ubuntu-desktop` with `kubuntu-desktop`, `xubuntu-desktop` or whatever flavour you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the hint of checking `/var/log/apt/history.log`. That saved my day. :)